# Replace this.href with this.title

Tags: javascript, href, title

The below code works perfectly to reveal an image when a user mouses over an hotspot of an image map.  The only problem?  When clicked 'this.href' of course takes the user to the hotspot image itself.  I'd like to reserve 'href' to send the users to the page of my choosing.

Is it possible to use "title" rather than 'href' to define the hotspot image?  If so, please show details, I'm very new to javascript, thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowPicC(sImage){document.housec.src = sImage}
 </script>

 <img border="0" src="main-image.png" width="640" height='640' usemap="#FPMap0">
 <map name="FPMap0">
 <area onmouseover='ShowPicC(this.href)' href='hotspot1.png' alt="thisalt" title="can-png-go-here.png" shape="circle"  coords="400,400,20">
 <area onmouseover="ShowPicC(this.href)" href="hotspot2.jpg" alt="youralt" title="can-png-go-here2.png" shape="circle" coords="420,420,20">
 <area onmouseover="ShowPicC(this.href)" href="hotspot3.jpg" alt="differentalt" title="can-png-go-here3.png" shape="circle" coords="440,440,20">
 <area onmouseover="ShowPicC(this.href)" href="hotspot4.jpg" alt="whateveralt" title="can-png-go-here4.png" shape="circle" coords="460,460,20">
 </map>

 <img name="housec" src="starter-hotspot-image.png" width="192" height="170">
```

Comment: Where is `title` in the HTML?

Comment: Thanks Tom Fenech, title added to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, although `title` isn't a valid property of `area`. Did you try it?

```
<area onmouseover="ShowPicC(this.title)" title="someotherimage.jpg" ...
```

You may be better off using a data attribute:

```
<area data-image="someotherimage.jpg" ...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: I did try it.  & Thank you @isherwood for the data-image idea!  It seems the most difficult part for me is how to alter the function inside the script for either title or data-image.  Would you know how to do it?

Comment: The function doesn't need to be altered. It accepts whatever value is passed.

Comment: Great you're right @isherwood!  this.title does work (yes, without altering the function).  But I'm having difficulty finding the correct way to get data-image to work.  It isn't 'this.data-image' is it?  Sorry, I've gone surfing around but couldn't find the correct syntax.  Also yes it looks like data-image is preferable.

Comment: Look at the link I included. It's a bit different as data attributes don't have native JavaScript methods.

Comment: Yes I looked at the code but am a bit too new at Javascript to understand how to alter the script...  If I don't hear from you I guess I'll just stick with 'title'.  Thank you for all your help!